Can't get the user's location while the Flat List is scrolling
In a react native application using Expo, I have a FlatList to display items and functionality to get the user's location using getCurrentPositionAsync() from expo-location.
I get the location every 10 seconds and there are 40 items in the flat list.
Let's recreate the situation:
I launched the application, the location was received, everything works, the countdown of 10 seconds started until the next location is received. Then I start scrolling through the flat list, and at the same moment an asynchronous function is called to get the location. The location will not come to me until I finish scrolling the flat sheet. And if within 5 seconds after calling the function, the scrolling has not stopped, then catch catches the error:
Error code:  Cannot obtain current location: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" , E_LOCATION_UNAVAILABLE.

And as soon as the scroll is closed, the application crashes. Sentry catches the C++ Exception St13runtime_error.
What exactly is the reason for this behavior and how to fix it?
Here is the code of getting location:

 const [location, setLocation] = useState<ILocation | null>();
  const interval = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>();
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  const locationPermission = useSelector(
    (state) => state.persistedData.locationPermission
  );

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const updateLocation = async () => {
    if (isFocused) {
      try {
        const { coords } = await getCurrentPositionAsync({
          accuracy: Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        });
        console.log(coords);
        setLocation({
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error code: ", error.message);
  
        if (error.code === "E_LOCATION_UNAVAILABLE") {
          console.log(error.code);
        } else if (error.code === "E_NO_PERMISSIONS") {
          alert(
            "We need access to your location to provide a list of nearby places to use the harbor, i.e. where to swim and fish etc. Please change the access rights in the device or app settings to use all the features of the application."
          );
          dispatch(setLocationPermission(false));
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  // This useEffect was written to prevent location errors when user changes screen or app state changes to inactive or background!!
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!locationPermission.permission) {
      setLocation(null);
      if (interval.current) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
        interval.current = null;
      }
      return;
    }
  
    updateLocation();

  
    if (!interval.current && isFocused) {
      interval.current = setInterval(updateLocation, 10000);
    } else if (interval.current && !isFocused) {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      interval.current = null;
    }
  
    return () => {
      if (interval.current) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
        interval.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [locationPermission.permission, isFocused]);



I tried to replace Flat List with Flash List,
I tried to add InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions()
I also implemented clearing the interval when calling onScrollBeginDrag and restoring it when calling onMomentumScrollEnd in the FlatList and it works, but this is not my option, because I have many such Flat Lists in my application in different places, so I have to write a lot of code, it will become unreadable and may conflict with the already written code
